# UILabel text wrap show second line with one space before the first line in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I just use the custom Uilabel in a tableview which i have given a some text lines from my sqlite table.I set label.numberoflines=0;It wraps but second line appear one space before first line. How to get the second line in the same x position which the first line is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your UILabel is left aligned:

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

or do it in ib if you're using it.

Comment: I am coding in IOS6 here I use txtlabel_custom.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; but still it happens

Comment: hmm are you sure that the sqllite data doesn't contain the space (use nslog or debugger)

Comment: `UITextAlignmentLeft` is a deprecated in iOS 8.